# Can't SSH to host using Fugu due to warning?

Tags: networking, macos, ssh, vmware-fusion

I'm using [Fugu](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/fugu/) to connect to an OpenBSD guest in VMware Fusion. I connect using an IP address, and not a hostname. Fugu is throwing the following ***warning*** (not ***error***), and then abandoning the connection:

[image]

I could understand it abandoning the connection if there is an error, but the warning (and its message) make no sense.

I *think* what happened is the guest got a new DHCP address, so its failing `StrictHostKeyChecking`. In this case, the host's public key did not change - only its IP address changed.

Fugu does not ask me what to do, and does not appear to have options for SSH sessions (only FTP sessions).

Can anyone confirm that's the problem I am experiencing with Fugu? If so, how do I proceed?

Comment: Typically there's a file with known hosts - I'd suggest deleting the entry for that server, or just clearing it out.

Comment: Take a look at this Q&A on SO: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840012/ssh-remote-host-identification-has-changed